# Reversed geocoding with html 5 sometimes fail with response from google

Tags: php, ajax, api, caching, geocoding

I have a html 5 geolocation service that is supposed to show city of the user when geo position is allowed. This works about 10 times and fails the last time. I have tried to set timeout on the ajax call etc but cannot seem to make it work. I seems like is failes more often when i clear cookies and restart the browser, but not every time. This is my code:

```
// Get geo location co-ordinates
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
  // If accepted by user
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, showError, {timeout: 20000});
  // If declined by user
  }else{ 
    jQuery('#location').hide().html('Fail').fadeIn('slow');
  }
});

// Convert co-ordinates to city by using ajax request with google api
function showLocation(position){

  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log( longitude + latitude );

  jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: themePath + '/geolocation/getlocation.php',
    data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude,
    // timeout: 1000,
      success:function(msg){
        if(msg){
          jQuery(".front-hero-loader").hide();
          jQuery("#location").hide().html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
          // console.log( longitude + latitude + "fail" );
          jQuery("#location").hide().html('Fail').fadeIn('slow');
        }
      }
  });
}
// Error Callback for geolocation
function showError(error) {
  jQuery("#location").hide().html('Fail').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

And this is the php file to convert coordinates to city and return to ajax call

```
<?php
//if latitude and longitude are submitted
if(!empty($_POST['latitude']) && !empty($_POST['longitude'])){
    //send request and receive json data by latitude and longitude
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($_POST['latitude']).','.trim($_POST['longitude']).'&sensor=false';
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $location = $data->results[0]->address_components[3]->short_name;
    $status = $data->status;

    //if request status is successful
    if($status == "OK"){
        //get address from json data
        $location;
    }else{
        $location =  'Fail';
    }
    //return address to ajax 
    echo $location;
}
?>
```

Comment: You are checking $status == "OK", but $status is undefined in the code.

Comment: Youre right, updated the code but the issue remains.